# ros package for Kuka LWR IV FRI

Tags: ros, kuka, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I would like to know how we can use our Kuka LWR IV as a ROS node. I know that this robot is not in the list of robots that ROS supports, but you can do it through Orocos RTT. Is there any other way to do it? any documentation, tutorial or advice is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48857/ros-package-for-kuka-lwr-iv-fri/) by [mr_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/3644/mr_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to use KUKA LWR with ros is to use OROCOS which is integrated with ROS. You should look at code in our repos https://github.com/organizations/RCPRG-ros-pkg . An other important thing is that you need to use xenomai if you need command rate below 5ms.

---

Originally posted by [konradb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/2207/konradb3/) with karma: 71 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Risto Kojcev](https://answers.ros.org/users/12756/risto-kojcev/) on 2014-06-17**:
do I need xenomai or I can use other real time patches for the Linux Kernel? Is orocos somehow bounded to Xenomai?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While there doesn't appear to be any support for Kuka robots yet, the [ROS Industrial](http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial) 'section' of ROS seems like the best place to look / ask for support. They might be interested in adding support for it, if they are not already working on it.

Using Orocos RTT seems easier than any of the embedded robot languages most of their supported arms use (V+, Karel).

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1